# windows azure kubernetes - Running a container(simple version)

Tags: azure, google-compute-engine, kubernetes

From the [steps](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/azure.md) on kubernetes github

The section "Running a container (simple version)"

```
cluster/kubecfg.sh -p 8080:80 run dockerfile/nginx 2 myNginx

kubecfg.go:443] Error: request [&http.Request{Method:"POST", URL:(*url.URL)(xxx), Proto:"HTTP/1.1", ProtoMajor:1, ProtoMinor:1, Header:http.Header{"Authorization":[]string{"Basic xxx =="}}, Body:ioutil.nopCloser{Reader:(*bytes.Buffer)(xxx)}, ContentLength:573, TransferEncoding:[]string(nil), Close:false, Host:"myVM.cloudapp.net", Form:url.Values(nil), PostForm:url.Values(nil), MultipartForm:(*multipart.Form)(nil), Trailer:http.Header(nil), RemoteAddr:"", RequestURI:"", TLS:(*tls.ConnectionState)(nil)}] failed (502) 502 Bad Gateway: <html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your apiserver is not up; if it's just slow, this should be transient.

But it's more likely you'll need to log into your master VM, and look in /var/log/kube-apiserver.log to see why it failed to start.